# Moq mocked call returns null if using setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am writing tests for a C# application, using Moq. My test initialiser has the following code:

```
UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

_serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
_serviceMock.Setup(mock => mock.GetSearchInfoAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), It.IsAny<identifierType>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).Callback(() => _count++);
unityContainer.RegisterInstance(typeof(IService), _serviceMock.Object, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

I want to test that a call is made only once. I am trying it like this:

```
int _count = 0;

[TestMethod]
public void Properties_Test()
{
    _serviceMock.Verify(mock => mock.GetSearchInfoAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), It.IsAny<identifierType>(), It.IsAny<bool>()), Times.Exactly(1), "Invocation was performed " + _count + " times but was expected only once!");
}
```

This is the method where it actually gets called:

```
private void Search(string queryValue, identifierType identifierType)
{
    CancellationToken cancellationToken;

    lock (_syncLock)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    }

    IService Service = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IService>();

    Service.GetSearchInfoAsync(cancellationToken, new[] {queryValue}, identifierType)
        .ContinueWith(
            task =>
            {
                // Do stuff
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

The problem is that if I use this line as detailed above,

```
_serviceMock.Setup(mock => mock.GetSearchInfoAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), It.IsAny<identifierType>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).Callback(() => _count++);
```

this returns null and generates a NullPointerException:

```
Service.GetSearchInfoAsync(cancellationToken, new[] {queryValue}, identifierType)
```

However, if I comment out that line, the tests run fine (albeit not counting the number of calls).

What am I doing wrong? This is my first time using Moq for this and as far as I can tell I've implemented the count functionality correctly.

**EDIT:** Following Chris Sinclair's suggestion, I've changed the initialiser to this, which fixed the issue:

```
UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

_serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
Task<IEnumerable<ISearchResult>> task = new Task<IEnumerable<ISearchResult>>(Enumerable.Empty<ISearchResult>);
_serviceMock.Setup(mock => mock.GetSearchInfoAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), It.IsAny<identifierType>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(task).Callback(() => _count++);
unityContainer.RegisterInstance(typeof(IService), _serviceMock.Object, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: When you "Setup" the method, you set a callback but you don't set a return value. If I had to guess, that will make the method return the default value for the return type, and it looks like that would be some sort of `Task<>` (so default value would be `null`). Your `Search` method calls the mocked method, which returns `null`, then it calls `.ContinueWith()` on that null reference. Maybe try adding a `.Returns()` to your setup which creates a dummy `Task<>`? Sorry, I'm not 100% positive on this.

Comment: You were correct, that fixed it! Please factor out your reply into an answer so I can mark it as the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you "Setup" the method, you set a callback but you don't provide a return value. As such, when the mocked method is called, it will return the default value for the return type (in this case, a `Task<>` type will result in a `null` return value). As such, when your `Search` method calls your mocked `GetSearchInfoAsync` method, it receives a `null` reference which naturally fails when it later attempts to invoke `.ContinueWith` on it.

Try adding a `.Returns()` which feeds a dummy `Task<>` to your mocked method:

```
_serviceMock.Setup(mock => mock.GetSearchInfoAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), It.IsAny<identifierType>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
    .Returns(new Task<IEnumerable<ISearchResult>>(Enumerable.Empty<ISearchResult>))
    .Callback(() => _count++);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to drop the count and Setup as I noticed it's not really needed. Have a look and see if you can answer this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205261/moq-verify-number-of-calls-works-if-test-called-alone-but-not-if-called-along-o

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry about your other question, don't really know. My first guess would be to skip the shared resources and try putting _all_ the setup in the failing test with local variables (no fields or shared resources). If the test now passes, then you know there's an issue with the way you're setting it up. If it still fails, then you know there's an issue with the test itself.