# Moq Verify number of calls works if test called alone, but not if called along other tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am working on a `C#` application, which uses `Moq` for testing. I am trying to count the number of times a method is being called. The following piece of code is used to initialise the test objects:

```
private Mock<IService> _serviceMock;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    MockServices();

    Rule rule = new Rule(
        // Parameters
        );

    RuleItem = new RuleItem(rule);
}

private void MockServices()
{
    UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

    _serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
    unityContainer.RegisterInstance(typeof (IService), _serviceMock.Object, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    UnityServiceLocator locator = new UnityServiceLocator(unityContainer);
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
}
```

The method in question is being called when the `RuleItem` is being instantiated with a `Rule` and debugging shows that it is being hit. This is the code where it gets called:

This is the method where it actually gets called:

```
private void Search(string queryValue, identifierType identifierType)
{
    CancellationToken cancellationToken;

    lock (_syncLock)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    }

    IService Service = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IService>();

    Service.GetSearchInfoAsync(cancellationToken, new[] {queryValue}, identifierType)
        .ContinueWith(
            task =>
            {
                // Debugging shows that it reaches in here on each test.
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

This is my test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Properties_Test()
{
    _serviceMock.Verify(
        mock => mock.GetSearchInfoAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), It.IsAny<identifierType>(), It.IsAny<bool>()), 
        Times.Exactly(1), 
        "Invocation was not performed only once!");
}
```

The surprising thing is that the test passes if it's executed by itself but it fails if it is executed together with other tests. The exception is as follows:

> Test method Package.Views.RuleViewModelTest.Properties_Test threw
>   exception:  Moq.MockException: Invocation was performed 1 times but
>   was expected only once! Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1
>   times, but was 0 times: mock =>
>   mock.GetSearchInfoAsync(It.IsAny(),
>   It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(),
>   It.IsAny())
>   No setups configured.
>   No invocations performed.

Comment: `SetLocatorProvider` is a static method, which means that all your UTs in this context are not isolated from each other... `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);` is the source of your problem.... You execute the verification on a different instance.

Comment: But wouldn't the provider be changed on every single run on doing this? ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator); If not, what would be a solution?

Comment: In my opinion service locator is an anti-pattern and you should never use it in UT... the simplest solution I can offer you is to wrap `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IService>();` into a virtual method, then use partial-mock to override this method...

Comment: Sadly that's not an option as I cannot change the implementation ... Any other ideas?

Comment: Use code weaving tools like MsFakes...

Comment: I know this sounds bad, but when I said I can't change the implementation, that also meant I can't add references. All I have is Moq ... Any other ideas?

Comment: MsFakes doesn't add anything to your project under test, it does add an alternative assembly to the test project. BTW you can use Mutex in setup\teardown - this action will execute all test in the context in a serial pipeline...